# Equivalent to @XmlElement.required in @XmlPath in EclipseLink MOXy

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

How to implement `@XmlElement.required` flag using `@XmlPath` annotation in [**EclipseLink MOXy**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) 2.4.1 version?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `@XmlElement(required=true)` along with the `@XmlPath` annotation to specify that the leaf element is required.

**Customer**

Below is a sample domain model with two fields mapped with `@XmlPath` on one of them I've also used `@XmlElement(required=true)`.

```java
package forum13854920;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    @XmlPath("personal-info/first-name/text()")
    private String firstName;

    @XmlPath("personal-info/last-name/text()")
    @XmlElement(required=true)
    private String lastName;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To use MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**XML Schema**

Below is the XML schema that corresponds to the domain model.  Note how the `last-name` element does not have `minOccurs="0"`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xsd:complexType name="customer">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="personal-info" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element name="first-name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                  <xsd:element name="last-name" type="xsd:string"/>
               </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
         </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

**Demo**

The following demo code can be used to generate the XML schema.

```java
package forum13854920;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        jc.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {

            @Override
            public Result createOutput(String namespaceURI, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                result.setSystemId(suggestedFileName);
                return result;
            }

        });
    }

}
```

---

Currently [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) does not have the equivalent of the `required` property on the `@XmlElement` annotation for the other segments of the path.  If you are interested in this behaviour please enter an enhancement request using the link below:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink